# What language is Main.Storyboard's source code written in for Xcode/swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm studying swift and trying to delete a UI button. While I was doing that I was looking at the source code for the Main.storybaord file. I don't recognize what language it is and was curious. What language is swift/xcode's main.storybaord's source code written in?

Comment: It's [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your storyboard file in the Project panel, and **Open As > Source Code**, you will find the storyboard file is as **XML** type.

Generally, we suggest you create the storyboard with the UI tools.